# How to give different filename to ftp file while downloading in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have:

1) files on ftp with names (@track.path.path) like "b573c8150fbc0dc6f5de6a9d4db79277_128.mp3" etc

2) in database each file has nice name (@track.fname) like "U2_-_Ill_go_crazy_if_i_dont_go_crazy_tonight.mp3"

Question:
Is there any way to give name from DB to ftp file when he is downloading?

music_controller.rb:

```
   def download
     @track = Mp3File.find(params[:id])
     case params[:bitrate]
       when "64"
         send_file(@track.path.path + "_128.mp3")
       when "128"
         send_file(@track.path.path + "_64.mp3")
       when "32"
         send_file(@track.path.path + "_32.mp3")
     end
   end
```

I want user to have nice name "U2_-_Ill_go_crazy_if_i_dont_go_crazy_tonight.mp3" on his device after downloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`send_file` takes a `:filename` option that does precisely this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set [the `Content-Disposition` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1) to set the filename regardless of the url:

```
def download
  @track = Mp3File.find(params[:id])
  headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="#{@track.fname}"'

  # ...
end
```